# Neo4J Insertion taking time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a query which is taking the long time to insert in neo4j roughly the query looks like following :

```
create index on :symaccess_symdev(dir_port);
create index on :symaccess_symdev(host_lun);
create index on :symaccess_symdev(ini_tiator_group_name);
create index on :symaccess_symdev(sym_dev);

CALL apoc.load.json('file:////root/output/1530115956414/dev.json') YIELD 
value AS row UNWIND row.symdev AS symdevs 
MERGE (accesssymdev:symaccess_symdev {
  sym_dev: symdevs.sym_dev,
  host_lun: symdevs.host_lun,
  ini_tiator_group_name: symdevs.ini_tiator_group_name,
  dir_port: symdevs.dir_port
}) 
ON CREATE SET 
  accesssymdev.attr_percentage = symdevs.attr_percentage,
  accesssymdev.cap_mb = toFloat(symdevs.cap_mb),
  accesssymdev.physicaldevicename = symdevs.physicaldevicename;
```

Comment: Can you give the `explain` of this query ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `sym_dev` property value is unique for every `symaccess_symdev` node, then this query may be faster:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:////root/output/1530115956414/dev.json') YIELD 
value AS row UNWIND row.symdev AS symdevs 
MERGE (a:symaccess_symdev {sym_dev: symdevs.sym_dev})
ON CREATE SET
  a.host_lun = symdevs.host_lun,
  a.ini_tiator_group_name = symdevs.ini_tiator_group_name,
  a.dir_port = symdevs.dir_port,
  a.attr_percentage = symdevs.attr_percentage,
  a.cap_mb = toFloat(symdevs.cap_mb),
  a.physicaldevicename = symdevs.physicaldevicename;
```

A `MERGE` will only use at most one index, so your current query will cause the Cypher planner to pick one index (out of the 4 that are applicable). After using that index to generate a set of candidate nodes, it would still need to check the other 3 properties for each candidate node. If it had picked an index that is not very selective (because there tends to be many nodes with the same property value), then a lot of work would need to be done per `MERGE`.

Assuming that the `sym_dev` property value is unique, the above query simplifies the `MERGE` so that it will quickly discover whether the wanted `symaccess_symdev` node existed, and without needing to check any other properties.